# Flash HTML5 canvas conditions for audio.pause and resume function

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-canvas, soundjs

Despite my readings I'm still limited in javascipt / soundJS syntax with using flash html5 canvas. I would like to pause and resume my sound with mouseover and mouseout events on the same button. I mean:

- You hover the button: the music starts.
- You mouseout: the music pauses.
- You hover it again: it resumes from the position it has been paused with precedence.

According to the [SoundInstance Class doc](http://docs.createjs.jp/SoundJS_docs-0.4.0/classes/SoundInstance.html#method_resume), you can do that with
`myInstance.pause();` and `myInstance.resume();` methods. And I suppose "var sound;"  behaves likes "myInstance" since `sound.pause();` works.

With the js code below I can pause the sound and resume my sound, but not on the same button, I need a button_2 to do that.

I think I'm missing a condition in mouseover function to "check if the sound is paused or not and then resume it or start playing.

```
var sound;
function fl_MouseOverHandler(){  
    sound = playSound("monstres"); 
}  
this.mybutton.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);  


function fl_MouseOutHandler()  { 
    sound.pause();  
} 
this.mybutton.addEventListener("mouseout", fl_MouseOutHandler);  

function fl_MouseOverHandler_2(){  
    sound.resume();
}  
this.mybutton_2.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler_2);
```

Any hint or link is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about something like this?

```
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlayback(){
    if(isPlaying){
        isPlaying = false;
        sound.pause();
    } else {
        isPlaying = true;
        sound.resume();
    }
}

this.some_button.addEventListener("some_event", togglePlayback );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are an angel sent to earth.
Meanwhile I've found dome docs on javascript and managed to code my beloved function with something in the same spirit using a boolean variable. 
Here's my code:

```
var playing = new Boolean(false);

function fl_MouseOverHandler() {
    if (playing == false) {
        exportRoot.soundInstance = playSound("monstres");
        playing = true;
        exportRoot.soundInstance.on("complete", handleComplete);
        function handleLoop(event) {
            exportRoot.soundInstance = playSound("monstres");
        }
    } else {
        exportRoot.soundInstance.resume();
        }
    }
this.bout_zone_son.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

function fl_MouseOutHandler() {
    exportRoot.soundInstance.pause();
    }

this.bout_zone_son.addEventListener("mouseout", fl_MouseOutHandler);
```

I can't use if (playing) {....} syntax because:

- i must first fire the sound with my button and then check if it's palying or not to resume it or start it.
- I think I can't type sound.pause without first instanciating "sound =  playSound("mylinkedsoundfromlibrary"); or my case exportRoot.soundInstance = playSound("monstres");

Well, thanx anyway for giving a shot in the right direction.

Comment: In order to use the `playSound` method (that Flash generates) as you have shown, you have to modify it. I believe the existing function just calls `createjs.Sound.play(...)`, and does not return the instance that is generated. It should instead `return createjs.Sound.play(...);`.